# ¿Cómo obtener el ultimo registro de un grupo?

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada product_stock la cual guarda la cantidad que tiene un producto en cierto fecha (como un movimiento)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener la ultima cantidad de cada producto, por tal razón hice la siguiente consulta

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT s.`fk_producto`,IF(s.`movimiento`='RETIRO',s.`stock`-
s.`cantidad`,s.`stock`+s.`cantidad`) cantidad,s.`fecha`
FROM `products_stock` s
WHERE s.`fk_organizacion`='1496367463'
ORDER BY s.`fk_producto`,s.`fecha` DESC) stock 
GROUP BY stock.fk_producto
```

La subconsulta me muestra cada producto ordenado por la ultima fecha

```
SELECT s.`fk_producto`,IF(s.`movimiento`='RETIRO',s.`stock`-
s.`cantidad`,s.`stock`+s.`cantidad`) cantidad,s.`fecha`
FROM `products_stock` s
WHERE s.`fk_organizacion`='1496367463'
ORDER BY s.`fk_producto`,s.`fecha` DESC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El producto con id 22 tiene como cantidad mas reciente 9, si agrupo con producto y ejecuto la consulta principal obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver el producto 22 trae la cantidad 12, e incluso agregue el campo fecha para que se viera que no traer el primer registro, ¿no se supone que cuando agrupo trae siempre el primer registro? o, ¿qué otra manera se puede hacer esta consulta?

Comment: A ver si entendi, quieres que la fila donde esta el valor `fk_producto 22` te aparezca de primero?

Comment: No, quiero saber si con un group by trae el primero registro de cada grupo, y si es asi, por que no me funciona, ya que en el ejemplo se puede notar eso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo esencial de tu pregunta es "Quiero obtener la ultima cantidad de cada producto". Para hacer eso, una posibilidad es la siguiente:

```
SELECT  stock.fk_producto,
    IF(stock.movimiento = 'RETIRO', stock.stock - stock.cantidad, stock.stock + stock.cantidad) cantidad,
    stock.fecha
    FROM products_stock stock
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT     s.fk_organizacion,
                s.fk_producto,
                MAX(s.fecha) AS fecha
                FROM products_stock s
                GROUP BY s.fk_organizacion,
                     s.fk_producto
        ) ultimos
        ON ultimos.fk_producto = stock.fk_producto
        AND ultimos.fecha = stock.fecha
        and ultimos.fk_organizacion = stock.fk_organizacion
    WHERE stock.fk_organizacion = '1496367463'
```

Explicación:

- Armamos una subconsulta `ultimos`que nos dá la última fecha de cada producto
- Luego hacemos un `INNER JOIN` contra dicha subconsulta y obtendremos los últimos registros de `products_stock`

Tener en cuenta:

- Que los productos que no tengan ningún stock no van a aparecer, si lo quisieras ver deberías agregar la tabla de productos y hacer un `LEFT JOIN` a esta misma consulta.
- Esto funciona siempre que no existan fechas "repetidas" por producto.
- Lo que te paso está escrito "a ciegas" ya que no tengo forma de probarlo, pero la idea entiendo que es sencilla de entender

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Si funciona la consulta, gracias, aunque quisiera saber tambien cuando se hace un group by cualquiera no se supone que trae el primer registro de cada grupo? y si no es asi, que se supone que trae

Comment: @Lemi, `GROUP BY` implícitamente ordena por defecto (es decir, en ausencia de designadores ASC o DESC), pero la clasificación implícita de `GROUP BY` está obsoleto. Esto es para permitir al optimizador ordenar agrupaciones de la manera que considere más eficiente y evitar la sobrecarga de clasificación. [Aca mas info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: No, el `GROUP BY` agrupa datos repetidos, en el ejemplo que te pase agrupa por `fk_organizacion` y `fk_producto` y para la fecha usamos una función de agregación `MAX` que nos devuelve la fecha máxima de cada grupo

Answer (score 0):

Es por el orden amigo, toma primero los productos y después las fechas. Cambia tu código a este.

```
SELECT s.fk_producto,IF(s.movimiento='RETIRO',s.stock-
s.cantidad,s.stock+s.cantidad) cantidad,s.fecha
FROM products_stock s
WHERE s.fk_organizacion='1496367463'
ORDER BY s.fecha,s.fk_producto DESC
```

Permiteme saber si te funciono

Comment: Nada, me sigue dando el mismo resultado

Answer (score 0):

Veo que esta pregunta tiene mas de un año, pero quizá la respuesta sea de utilidad para otra persona. `MySQL` no cuenta con la Función `LAST` y `FIRST` de otros motores. `MAX` y `MIN` obtienen los valores máximo y mínimo respectivamente mientras que `LAST` y `FIRST` obtienen el último y primer Registro, pero desafortunadamente para los usuarios de `MySQL` no disponemos de estas funciones. La única alternativa a nivel de sentencia SQL ya te la dio Patricio Moracho ver su respuesta arriba. (Hace una subconsulta agrupando por Organización y por mes y obtienes solo 3 campos: Organización, Producto y MAX(Fecha)MaxFecha a esa subconsulta le asignas un alias y luego haces un JOIN con la misma tabla, pero si te fijas en el `JOIN` usas los tres campos obtenidos el la subconsulta con sus respectivos en la tabla original)

Con la limitación de que si se repite el mismo producto mas de una ves en la misma fecha puedes tener un resultado inesperado en cuyo caso te tocaría hacerlo por programación recorreiendo tu maestro de productos y por cada producto puedes enviar una sentencia semejante a la siguiete: `SELECT * FROM stock WHERE Producto = '" + Codigo + "' ORDER BY Fecha DESC LIMIT 1;` Esta sentencia te trae el último registro en la tabla stock de un producto determinado por la variable Código. Si haces esto dentro de un bucle puedes obtener el resultado que necesitas.